# Python: how to implement copy for base class which works for inherited with new attributes

Tags: python, design-patterns

How to implement copy for base class which works for inherited with new attributes w/o implementing `__copy__` for inherited class (implying dumb copy for new attributes)?

I.e. we have class with one user-defined and one calculated (or external reference, should not be copied) fields. So copy should create instance, based only on user-defined field:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = a+1

    def __copy__(self):
        return A(self.a)
```

At this moment `copy` works fine.

Then we introduce inherited class, and it's constructor calculates args for base constructor based on it's own args, and also introduce new field, so signature of inherited constructor is completely different and unknown (in common) for base class:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, c):
        A.__init__(self, c+100)
        self.c=c
```

At this moment `copy` obviously works not fine, returning `A` instance. Of cause we can implement own `__copy__` for inherited class, but it's extremely inconvenient, when we introduce some attributes, which should be copied in just ordinary manner. So what I'd like to achieve, is to copy "A part" of inherited class B by `A.__copy__`, but remains by standard copy, w/o re-implementing `__copy__` for all inherited classes. So are there any 'design pattern' for such situations?

UPD:
I'd like to reformulate example from `copy` to `deepcopy`, which is more close to real case. So the idea is the same - we have to manage deepcoping of class A, which contains reference which should not bee deepcopied (i.e. link to container, in which object contains). But we don't want to manage deepcoping of inherited classes.

```
from copy import deepcopy

class A:

    def __init__(self, content, container):
        self.content = content
        self.container = container

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return A(deepcopy(self.content, memo), self.container)

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, attr):
        A.__init__(self, [1,2,3], self)
        self.attr = attr

b = B(123)
b1=deepcopy(b) # wrong!
```

Looks like I found the pattern which is suitable in my particular case (thx @mhawke): copy everything first, and then deepcopy only necessary fields.

```
class A:
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        o = copy(self)
        o.content = deepcopy(self.content)
        return o
```

But it not solve problem in common case: for deepcopy I'd like to deepcopy inherited attributes, not copy it, and manage deepcoping for overrides only if necessary.

Comment: What is wrong with `copy.copy()`? It will copy an object of the inherited class(es) to an instance of the same class.

Comment: I suppose in this particular case nothing wrong. Maybe better to think about deepcopy, there are many cases when base class deepcopy should be overridden to exclude coping some links, i.e. link to adjacent object in some list. The question is how to implement base class copy, which works fine for typical overrides.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, this would work - you "only" have to override `_copyattrs` -, now I'm not sure this is any better than just overriding `__copy__`.

```
class A(object):
    _copyattrs = ["a"]

    def __copy__(self):
        args = [getattr(self, attrname) for attrname in self._copyattrs]
        return type(self)(*args) 


class B(A):
    _copyattrs = ["c"]
```

Comment: Not so good, cause we just need some overrides. What i'd like to achieve is that base class will call some 'standard' copy procedure for the whole class, except part managed by base class 'A'.